# Remove everything from a string expect content between span

Tags: php, regex

is there any good way to remove everything from a string except the content inside a `<span>` tag?

Example:

```
$myString = "mso:dkdlfkdl */1134*/** <span>Hello</span>";

i want:
$myNewString = '<span>Hello</span>';
```

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it the other way around: you want to get only the span tags and discard everything else. That can be done easily using regular expressions and then imploding the results back into one string:

```
$myString = "mso:dkdlfkdl */1134*/** <span>Hello</span>";

// Find all span elements and put them in $matches
preg_match_all("~(<span>.*?</span>)~", $myString, $matches);

// Combine all spans into one string
$myNewString = implode('', $matches[0]);
```